# Adding property disabled not working

Tags: jquery

I have to disable a button on click.Using below code but its not working.
Below code is using jquery

```
$('#someid').prop('disabled', true);
```

Any solution?

Comment: Your code should have worked

Comment: _on click_....You should add this too. As the posted line of code is absolutely valid. Check the browser's console for any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property and attribute have different behaviours.
See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/4485651

Instead use

```
$('#someid').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: OP's way is more preferred way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
})
```